# Error "uninitialized constant ActionController::CgiRequest>" when running Mongrel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, mongrel

I am running a ruby application (Redmine) with Mongrel. It can start successfully, however, once it gets an HTTP request, it hits below error:

```
** Signals ready.  TERM => stop.  USR2 => restart.  INT => stop (no restart).
** Rails signals registered.  HUP => reload (without restart).  It might not work well.
** Mongrel 1.2.0.pre2 available at 0.0.0.0:9001
** Use CTRL-C to stop.
2012-10-20 11:20:21 -0700: **Error calling Dispatcher.dispatch #<NameError: uninitialized constant ActionController::CgiRequest>
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:76:in `block in process'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'**
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `process'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/lib/mongrel.rb:165:in `block in process_client'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/lib/mongrel.rb:164:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/lib/mongrel.rb:164:in `process_client'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/lib/mongrel.rb:291:in `block (2 levels) in run'
```

Does anyone have any clue?

Comment: Try updating mongrel if not work try thin

Comment: Thanks. Thin is worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be an issue of **how to start Mongrel**:

ruby script/rails server mongrel   --> This successfully starts my ruby app.

mongrel_rails start                --> This brings the above error info.

**What is the difference of these two commands?**

My ruby app is Redmine.

Comment: I have just battled through two days of setting redmine up. your 'answer' is indeed correct for me too. but why? How much further did you get with this? did you set it up to run as a service and if so how? can you post a complete solution here?

Comment: I didn't spend time to go deep into "mongrel_rails".

Comment: Thx. I switched to thin as well and all is well